# moment-timezone: unix timestamps with timezones

Tags: node.js, unix, timestamp, momentjs

i am using momentjs.com with nodejs and im trying to get unix timestamps for multiple timezones, but sadly the the output is not correct.

code:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

var berlin = moment.tz('Europe/Berlin').unix();
var angeles = moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles').unix();
var london = moment.tz('Europe/London').unix();

console.log(berlin);
console.log(angeles);
console.log(london);
```

output:

```
1472241731
1472241731
1472241731
```

Comment: Does Unix time really allow time zones?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is *always* UTC based.  It is the same timestamp everywhere on the planet simultaneously.

Changing the time zone of a `moment` object using moment-timezone only affects the local time value, such as used with the `format` function (and others).  It does not change the moment in time being represented, and therefore does not change the underlying timestamp.

Comment: How can I get the absolute timestamp for a particular date-time in a specific timezone?

Comment: then it's not absolute is it? The unix timestamp is always in UTC timezone. You then need to create a Datetime object and set it's timezone to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Date.parse` to get a timestamp, like this

```js
const moment = require("moment-timezone")

const time = '2022-09-02 04:06:25'
var a = new Date(time).valueOf()                            
var b = Date.parse(moment.tz(time, "America/Chicago").format())

console.log(a)   // China 1662062785000  
console.log(b) // Chicago 1662109585000
```

Answer (score -3):

To show correct time to user for different timezone, we can add timezone offset to unix UTC timestamp

```
const convertToNewTimeZone = (timeInMilliseconds: number, timezone: string) => {
  const utcOffset = moment.tz(timeInMilliseconds, timezone).utcOffset();
  return moment(timeInMilliseconds)
    .add(utcOffset, 'minutes');
};
```

Note that if you are calculating time in browser, you may have to subtract the browser timezone offset

```
newTime.clone().subtract(moment().utcOffset(), 'minutes')
```

Comment: Adding or subtracting is almost never the correct way to apply a UTC offset.  You aren't adjusting for time zone, but rather you're picking a different moment in time.

Comment: Yes, the fact is the world all around is not at the same moment in time. It is the only way to show humans other than machines, what time is it in a selected timezone. We can store UTC on the server but on the website, we have to show the proper time.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not true.  If I ask three people around the world to all clap their hands exactly at the same time, we can all agree that that event occurred simultaneously (not getting into clock accuracy or relativity arguments).  That's what is meant by a "moment" or "instant" or "point in time".  It can be represented as `1472241731`, `1472241731000`, `"2016-08-26T20:02:11Z"`, `"2016-08-26T22:02:11+02:00"`, `"2016-08-26T21:02:11+01:00"`, or `"2016-08-26T13:02:11-07:00", but the specific meaning of the first two is *always* UTC - [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: *Adding* (say an hour) gives a different moment in time: `1472241731`,  `1472241731000`, `"2016-08-26T21:02:11Z"`, `"2016-08-26T23:02:11+02:00"`, `"2016-08-26T14:02:11-07:00"`.

Comment: We measure clock time with position of sun, thats why we manually change clock time on landing at any new country. If we still do it manually, we have to manually add offset to the time to get the actual time in current timezone. If we are saving time in UNIX timestamp (not readable for humans). We have to add offset and format it to make it readable for human. i am only talking with respect to usability.

Comment: Ah, but there's a huge difference between manually adjusting a mechanical wristwatch and setting the time on say a smart phone.  The former has only one basis of measurement, the local "wall time".  The latter has an internal UTC-based clock, an understanding of *time zone*, and an outward representation of local wall time.  Changing the time zone on a smart device only changes how the wall time is calculated, not what the internal clock does.  A Unix Timestamp is always a representation of the internal UTC-based clock, not of the local wall time.